# Al restaurar Jframe pierdo la representación de una imagen en la interfaz

Tags: java, java-swing

mi problema es que en una interfaz Java Swing tengo un JFrame con un JPanel, donde pinto una imagen que cargo desde fichero mediante el siguiente código:

```
    Graphics g = panel.getGraphics();
    panel.paintComponents( g );
    g.drawImage( imagenAMostrar , 0 , 0 , null );
```

El problema es que al minimizar la aplicación y restaurarla, se pierde la representación y la interfaz se queda en fondo gris.

He intentado solucionarlo añadiendo un "WindowsListener" con el evento "windowDeiconified" y ejecutando de nuevo el código anterior para volver a pintar la imagen, pero sigue sin funcionar.

Muchas gracias!

Editado: adjunto el código completo del JFrame que carga una imagen en el JPanel. Después de cargar una imagen cualquiera, se minimiza la app, se vuelve a restaurar, y la imagen desaparece.

```
public class Ventana {

// Frame de la interfaz
private JFrame frame;

// Paneles donde se muestran las huellas
private JPanel panelBordeIzquierda;
private JPanel panelHuellaIzquierda;

// Botones de la interfaz
private JButton btnCargarHuella;


public Ventana() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds( 100 , 100 , 920 , 570 );
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable( false );
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    // PANEL DE LA HUELLA IZQUIERDA
    panelBordeIzquierda = new JPanel();
    panelBordeIzquierda.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.LOWERED, null, null), "Huella original", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, new Color(0, 0, 0)));
    panelBordeIzquierda.setBounds(6, 40, 372, 504);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panelBordeIzquierda);
    panelBordeIzquierda.setLayout(null);

    panelHuellaIzquierda = new JPanel();
    panelHuellaIzquierda.setBounds(6, 18, 360, 480);
    panelBordeIzquierda.add(panelHuellaIzquierda);


    // ===== BOTÓN PARA CARGAR LA HUELLA =====
    btnCargarHuella = new JButton("Cargar Huella");
    btnCargarHuella.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            // Creamos el objeto JFileChooser
            JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
            FileNameExtensionFilter filtroImagen = new FileNameExtensionFilter( "JPG , PNG & GIF" , "jpg" , "png" , "gif" );
            fc.setFileFilter( filtroImagen );

            // Abrimos la ventana, guardamos la opcion seleccionada por el usuario
            int seleccion = fc.showOpenDialog( frame );

            // Si el usuario, pincha en aceptar
            if( seleccion == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION ){

                //Seleccionamos el fichero
                File fichero = fc.getSelectedFile();

                try {

                    BufferedImage huella = ImageIO.read( new File( fichero.getAbsolutePath() ) );

                    Graphics g = panelHuellaIzquierda.getGraphics();
                    panelHuellaIzquierda.paintComponents( g );
                    g.drawImage( huella , 0 , 0 , null );

                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    });

    btnCargarHuella.setBounds(7, 7, 117, 29);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnCargarHuella);

    frame.setVisible( true );

}

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    Ventana window = new Ventana();
}
```

}

Comment: Sin ver el resto del código es complicado saber qué está ocurriendo. ¿Puedes crear un [mcve]?

Comment: He incluido el ejemplo de interfaz eliminando todo lo que no es necesario para reproducir el problema. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Juan el problema radica en que insertas la imagen en el panel pero al cambiar el tamaño no es capaz de repintar la imagen para eso tenemos el metodo repaint() de la clase Canvas. Para solucionar tu problema cree una clase Lienzo:

```
public class Lienzo extends Canvas{
BufferedImage img;    

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {        
    g.drawImage( img , 0 , 0 , null );                            
}

public void setImage(BufferedImage img){
    this.img = img;      
}
}
```

En la clase Ventana agrega solo esto dentro del try catch:

```
  BufferedImage huella;
  huella = ImageIO.read( new File(fichero.getAbsolutePath() ) );

  lienzo.setImage(huella);//codigo nuevo
  lienzo.repaint();//codigo nuevo
```

Y por ultimo esto en las lineas donde creas el panel:

```
  lienzo = new Lienzo();//codigo nuevo
  panelHuellaIzquierda = new JPanel();
  panelHuellaIzquierda.setLayout(new BorderLayout());//codigo nuevo
  panelHuellaIzquierda.setBounds(6, 18, 360, 480);    
  panelHuellaIzquierda.add(lienzo);//codigo nuevo
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto, muchas gracias Tomas. Un saludo